# Unable to click with appium in ciscos anyconnect

Tags: appium

For our automation with real devices it is necessary to connect first to the VPN. So I installed anyconnect from cisco.
I can start the app, dismiss all the popups at the start, but I'm not able to get connected.

[anyconnect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIv3n.png)

The code snippet looks like this:

```
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android.avf")
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.cisco.anyconnect.ui.PrimaryActivity")

val appiumServer = URL(remoteTestingServer + "/wd/hub")
_driver = AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(appiumServer, capabilities)

_driver.findElements(By.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX).click()
```

I tried to use id, xpath, ClassName, etc. See the screenshot from the [UI Automator Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR5kb.png)

Comment: do you mean after dismissing all the popups, you are not able to click any elements on the screen ?

Comment: Exactly. Nothing on the first screenshot is not accessible. The buttons can be easily found with findElement(By.id("button1")) or via xpath. 

But _driver.findElements(By.id("cb_vpntoggle")) does not return the element

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Appium. As a workaround, after closing the popup/dialog, if we put the app in background and resume it, Appium will start detecting the elements again.

```
driver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
```